# Inline-block divs and multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css, containers

I am trying to hone my skills in on html5/css, by attempting a portfolio. The issue I am running into, is I have 3 inline-block divs, wrapped in a container div, but whenever I add more than 1 line of text (whether an h1 and h2 or h1 and a p) to only 1 div or all but 1, it shifts the other inline-block divs down. Shouldn't the inline-block div's stay where they are since the text is internal to that div? Furthermore, why are they breaking out of their parent/container div? Thanks for any help!

David

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Div - Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/alpha.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/grid-alpha.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="logo-bar">
            <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="maps">
                   <h1>Level Design</h1>
                   <p>Check out some maps!</p><p>And even cooler maps!</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="./sounds.html">
                <div class="sound">
                    <h1>Sounds</h1>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="proj">
                 <h1>Current</h1>
                 <p>Just a few notes here and there about my latest projects</p>
                 <p>And a few more here</p>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <footer>2020 Test | <a href="#">Contact</a></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*** Fonts ***/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Maven Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/mavenpro/v20/7Auup_AqnyWWAxW2Wk3swUz56MS91Eww8SX21nejog.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: #2d3436 !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, a, p {
  font-family: "Maven Pro";
  color: #dfe6e9;
}

a, a:active, a:hover, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dfe6e9;
}

.container {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
}

/** Div Backgrounds **/
#logo-bar {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maps {
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sound {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.proj {
background-color: #2c3e50;
height: 100%;
width: 33.33%;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.maps, .sound, .proj {
  text-align:center;
}


/*** Footer***/
footer {
  background-color: white/**#2c3e50**/;
  font-family: "Maven Pro";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font: #95a5a6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Try to give `vertical-align: top` to the inline-block divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you missing a property for your children container tag.

Add `vertical-align: top` for each element with a display`

Answer (score 0):

Let the classes maps, sound and proj the direct childs of the contanier div as follow

```
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="maps">
      <div>
        <h1>Level Design</h1>
        <p>Check out some maps!</p>
        <p>And even cooler maps!</p>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="./sounds.html" class="sound">
      <div>
        <h1>Sounds</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="proj">
      <h1>Current</h1>
      <p>Just a few notes here and there about my latest projects</p>
      <p>And a few more here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and float them to left

```
.maps, .sound, .proj{
  float: left;
}
```

and insted of repeating the same code for the three classes

use this code

```
.maps, .sound, .proj {
  text-align:center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
.maps {
  background-color: #7f8c8d;
}

.sound {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.proj {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

Comment: Good catch on not repeating the same code, but whats the advantage to floating left instead of vertical align top?